# Direct naked impersonation

Tags: authentication, keycloak, impersonation

I am having issues getting these steps to work, documented in [Securing Applications and Services Guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#direct-naked-impersonation). [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62148383/unable-to-reproduce-keycloak-direct-naked-impersonation) in stackoverflow showed an option which did not work as well. Can some one point me to the steps needed to fix this to allow naked impersonation?

Realm/client/policy/user details in the attached picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1S2Q.png)

Query:

```
curl -k -X POST
–header ‘Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded’
–data-urlencode “client_id=starting-client”
–data-urlencode “client_secret=.....”
–data-urlencode “grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange”
–data-urlencode “requested_subject=target-user”
https://localhost:8543/auth/realms/target_realm/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

Response:

```
{“error”:“access_denied”,“error_description”:“Client not allowed to exchange”}
```

Server logs:

```
22:40:08,396 WARN [org.keycloak.events] (default task-149) type=TOKEN_EXCHANGE_ERROR, realmId=target_realm, clientId=starting-client, userId=null, ipAddress=172.17.0.1, error=not_allowed, reason=‘client not allowed to impersonate’, auth_method=token_exchange, grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange, requested_subject=target-user, client_auth_method=client-secret
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the documentation in [Securing Applications and Services Guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#direct-naked-impersonation). Instead of add client policy for scope "user-impersonated", policy must added for scope "impersonate". Once that change was done it started to work.

Comment: Did that work for you? It still doesn't work for me even with `impersonate` scope

Comment: I also tried to resolve the issue changing "user-impersonated" to "impersonate", but that didn't do the trick. You managed to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below request format, and it should work. Tested and verified.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.kong.stg.vrpintegration.dev/requestJWT/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=bddf3a83-f4ec-45f6-afa0-cf9c94cb5518' \
--data-urlencode 'subject_token=xxxxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'audience=CLIENT_ID' \
--data-urlencode 'requested_token_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:refresh_token'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you checked the user exist, because if it doesn't exist it will return "Client cannot impersonate".

Also, there is some contraction on the doc.

Reading it from
[redhat keycloak](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_single_sign-on/7.2/html/securing_applications_and_services_guide/token-exchange#direct_naked_impersonation) it is using impersonate instead of user-impersonate in user permission while for [keycloak official doc](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#direct-naked-impersonation) it added user-impersonate, I used impersonate and added my starting-client. It works for me.